# VPN redundancy output point

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I want to make sure that my wireguard server0 will automatically switch to another output point (server1 or server2) depending on the network availability, hope schema will clarify what I mean:

```
WG client --->  WG Server0 (Entry point) --->  WG Server1 (output point1) # available 
                                        \--->  WG Server2 (output point2) # unavailable

WG client --->  WG Server0 (Entry point) --->  WG Server1 (output point1) # unavailable
                                        \--->  WG Server2 (output point2) # available
```

So, we got **two tunnels**:

first one between client to server0

second between server0 and server1 or server2 depending on public IP availability.

Final goal is to make sure server0 wireguard configuration has got correct public IP(server1 or server2) for "EndpointIP" directive.

any suggestions?

Comment: but as I understand it won't change if "output point1" turned off. 
Two ouput points have got separate public IPs. 
So, ideally, I need to make sure that on of them is used depending on their network availability.

Comment: well, the schema is pretty simple,
wireguard client connects to wireguard0 server (this server works as entry server for clients) -(tunnel)-> wireguard server1 or wireguard server2 (depending on public ip avaliability),
output point stands for public IPs.
I want to make sure that public ip(endpoint) in wireguard server0 changes to correct one depending on public ip availability of the wireguard servers1/2 (output points)

Comment: does that make 3 wireguard systems with two tunnels? one between wireguard client and wireguard server, and an other one between wireguard server and wireguard server1 ?

Comment: does that make 3 wireguard systems with two tunnels? yes, client - server0 - server1/2

Comment: Question didn't look very clear to me, now I think I understand it. Of course I'm not able to answer it "like this". Maybe you could add more details in the question so other people wishing to answer get it more easily than me. For example you wrote keepalived, so you could state that server1 and server2 are a keepalived cluster etc.

Comment: actually, I didn't included keepalived into the description. it seems that serverfault server's cache included it :)

Comment: hum just correct the question then (starting by removing the wrong tag). So both server1 and server2 could end up used at the same time rather than as failover, with multiple random public ips tied to the client. Looks way more complex suddenly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109632/discussion-between-marat-gainutdinov-and-a-b).